# Separate repository for each branch - GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am relatively new to `Git` and `GitHub`. I have a repository (say repo1) with the following `.git/config` file.

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github-userName:userName/repo1.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This repo has 3 branches. I am able to commit to all of them.

And another repository (say repo2) with the following `.git/config`:

```
core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github-userName:userName/repo2.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "development"]
        url = git@github-userName:userName/repo2_development.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/development/*
[remote "dev-epub"]
        url = git@github-userName:userName/repo2_dev-epub.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/dev-epub/*
[remote "bugfixes"]
        url = git@github-userName:userName/repo2_bugfixes.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/bugfixes/*
```

My question(s):
1. Which of the two is better for development purposes?
2. In the case of repo1, how does `Git` keep branches separate?
3. Given that I am able to commit to both projects with no errors, is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one repository for a project, what you really need here is branches.

You may take a look at the official documentation about branches:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is